# How can I define ContextKey in EntityFramework 7?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

In EF6 when I was using the Enable-migrations command was generating a file from type DbMigrationsConfiguration and in this file had a property with name 'ContextKey'.

I used this property to define the key from context and make relationship between tables in different contexts, same been in different classes.

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<WebApplication2.Context2>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        ContextKey = "eTurnContext";
    }
}
```

But in EF7 I don't have more this object DbMigrationsConfiguration. Are there an another way to solve this question in EF7?

Thanks

Comment: Have you found out the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As taken from my question / answer here - [Entity Framework Core Mutiple DbContext Migrations in same database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44694649/entity-framework-core-mutiple-dbcontext-migrations-in-same-database)

Previously, Entity Framework stored a snapshot of the model in the database. This resulted in Entity Framework having to query the database each time in order to work out what migrations have already run.

In EF7 migration history is stored in a snapshot in code (along with the existing migrations stored in the familiar Migrations folder). 
Each time you update the model and create a migration the snapshot file gets updated.

Therefore, there is no need for the ContextKey which was used in earlier version of Entity Framework.

It just works.

Answer (score -2):

Entity Framework Core (v7) has table `__EFMigrationsHistory` with two columns:

- MigrationId - string specified in Add-Migration PowerShell commandlet.
- ProductVersion - 1.0.1 - constant defined by Entity Framework Core

There is no ContextKey column that was present in EF6 `__MigrationsHistory` table. Maybe they have removed it because ContextKey was redundant because you may use ContextKey in your migration names.

Comment: You haven't really answered the question.  You've just stated that the ContextKey no longer exists in the migrations table but you haven't said why - see my answer below - I've spent a morning looking into this and playing around.